# "Download pipeline artifact" task output

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

"Download build artifacts" task has the output variable BuildNumber that makes it possible to get the id of the build the artifact was downloaded from. The new "Download pipeline artifact" task (which is preferred over the "Download build artifacts") does not have any the output variables. Is there a way to get the id of the build the artifact was downloaded from?

Also posted an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11784) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is about to [release a fix](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11784#issuecomment-600333922).

Answer (score 0):

There is workaround to get the build id of the downloaded artifact using [restful api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

To get the BuildId of the **Specific version**. You can refer to below below example.
First add a powershell task in your pipeline to run below scripts.

To get the definition id provided definition name(definition id will be used in the following scripts), check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for rest API.

```
$urldefinition ="https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<proj>/_apis/build/definitions?name=AboutSite-ASP.NET-CI&api-version=5.1"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urldefinition -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Get
$definition= $result.value
$definitionId = $definition[0].id
```

Then you can get the build id with below scripts:

```
$url="https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<proj>/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$definitionId&buildNumber=20191109AboutSite-ASP.NET-CI&statusFilter=completed&resultFilter=succeeded&api-version=5.1"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urldefinition -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Get
$build = $result.value
$id = $build[0].id
```

And then you can output the buildid for the following task to use with below script:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ArtifactBuildId;isOutput=true]$id"
```

To get  the latest build id you can simply use below [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{definition}?branchName={branchName}&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Comment: I need the id of the build that "Download pipeline artifact" task calculated, not specific or latest.

Comment: Hi @Alex I What i meant by specific and latest is according to the inputs of the download pipeline artifact task. the task calculates which artifact to download according to [inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) you specify, such as `definition,buildVersionToDownload,branchName,artifactName etc`. And you can use these inputs in the rest api to get the build id of the artifact using powershell scripts.

Comment: Even if I use this approach, there is a chance that I may calculate a different build id (another build may have completed or been tagged after "Download pipeline artifact" executed and before my script runs).

Comment: @Alex I I agree. Above is just a work around. It is not as handy as task's self output variables.I believe Microsoft development team is looking at this issue. Let's look forward to the feature being added soon.